# Using double for loop to work harmonically

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to traverse each worksheets in my workbook with for each but at the same time I wanted the for i = 1 to increase on every worksheet I traversed. I'm a beginner in Excel Vba any help would be appreciate it. Here's how my code looked like currently:

```
For Each xSh In Worksheets
        Windows("Forecast.xlsm").Activate
        xSh.Select
        For i = 2 To LastRow
... Some codes ...

next i

Next
```

This code would not loop perfectly as expected, Any solution to make both i and for each works harmonically, and where should I place the next method. Thank you^^

Comment: What do you mean with *"would not loop perfectly as expected"*? The syntax is okay. Is `LastRow` set to something meaningfull? And please get rid of `Activate` and `Select`-statements. And please indent your code correctly. And use `Option Explicit`. And declare your variables.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to move the Windows("Forecast.xlsm").Activate before the For Each cycle. You do not need to bring it to the front every time.

I also would suggest to use "option Explicit" and declare the variables. In this case
Dim xSh As Worksheet and Dim i As Long.

A comment: not always required to select the worksheet to work with it.

**e.g:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Example()
Dim i As Long
Dim xSh As Worksheet
Windows("Forecast.xlsm").Activate
For Each xSh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For i = 2 To LastRow
       ' Some Code
    Next i
Next xSh
```

Comment: Added code to answer to reflect suggested changes. Also added `ActiveWorkbook` to qualify the `Worksheets` object properly.

Comment: You should also avoid `Activate`. Instead, use `For Each xSh In Workbooks("Forecast.xlsm")`